# Refactoring SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have the below SQL query and I would like to refactor it. I am quite new to SQL, but I have learned somethings that I shouldn't do repeatedly in queries.

```
SELECT id,
(​SELECT​ ​COUNT​(*)​ ​FROM​ Table_1 ​
WHERE​ T3.​Id ​=​ randomID)​ ​AS​ ​'Column One Count'​,

(​SELECT​ ​COUNT​(*)​ ​FROM​ Table_2 ​
WHERE​ T3.​Id ​=​ randomID)​ ​AS​ ​'Column Two Count'​,

((​SELECT​ ​COUNT​(*)​ ​FROM​ Table_2 
​WHERE​ T3.​Id ​=​ randomID)​ ​/​

(​SELECT COUNT​(*)​ ​FROM​ Table_1 ​
WHERE​ T3.​Id ​=​ randomID))​ ​*​ 100 ​AS​ 'Column Three Percentage' 
FROM Table_3 T3
```

I have been advised not to use **SELECT *** often, So I have replaced each occurrence with:

```
SELECT COUNT(randomID)
```

This gives me the same result. I still think I can combine the the repeated elements into a more concise query however, but my level of SQL is just not good enough.

What are some ways to refactor this code to avoid repetition of similar queries?

Comment: Is there any more columns  from table1 and table2?

Comment: Or could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach uses `apply`:

```
select t3.id, t1.col1_cnt, t2.col2_cnt,
       t2.col2_cnt * 100.0 / t1.col1_cnt as col3_percentage
from Table_3 t3 outer apply
     (select count(*) as col1_cnt
      from table_1 t1
      where t3.id = t1.randomid
     ) t1 outer apply
     (select count(*) as col2_cnt
      from table_2 t2
      where t3.id = t2.randomid
     ) t2;
```

`apply` essentially lets you move the correlated subqueries to the `from` clause.  Once they are there, you can refer to the columns they generate more than one time.

EDIT:

If you are concerned about divide-by-zero, then use `nullif()`:

```
select t3.id, t1.col1_cnt, t2.col2_cnt,
       t2.col2_cnt * 100.0 / nullif(t1.col1_cnt, 0) as col3_percentage
```

Comment: Be carefull if you divide by 0, you should be use a case ;)

Comment: @Esperento57 . . . `nullif()` is preferable to `case` (it is shorter).

Comment: Its a method like an other :)

Answer (score 1):

for the counts, you might be able to just union the tables together; something like this:

```
select Ct = count(1)
from table_1
where Id = @RandomId
union 
select count(1)
from table_2
where Id = @RandomId'
```

I haven't fleshed out all the columns, but hopefully the general idea makes sense.

As far as the `select *` stuff goes, in general, you are right to avoid for a number of reasons (including it just being more data than you probably need, vulnerable to changes in schema, and pretty much shoots nonclustered indexes in the kneecaps). In older versions of SQL, that extended to things like `count(*)`. However as long as you're using SQL 2008+, `count()` (and a few other clauses like `EXISTS`) is smart enough to not actually select out any columns. So assuming you just want to count every row (even nulls), all these are equivalent

```
select 
    count(1),
    count(*),  
    count(primarykeycolumn) -- guaranteed not to be null
from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposition:

```
With CountT1 as (
select f1.randomID, count(*) NbT1
from Table_1 f1 inner join Table_3 f3 on f3.Id=f1.randomID
group by f1.randomID
),
CountT2 as (
select f1.randomID, count(*) NbT2
from Table_2 f1 inner join Table_3 f3 on f3.Id=f1.randomID
group by f1.randomID
)
select T3.Id, 
isnull(T1.NbT1, 0) as ​'Column One Count', 
isnull(T2.NbT2, 0) as ​'Column Two Count', 
case when T1.NbT1=0 then null else (T2.NbT2 /  T1.NbT1) * 100.0 end  as 'Column Three Percentage'
from Table_3 T3
left outer join CountT1 T1 on T3.Id=T1.randomID
left outer join CountT2 T2 on T3.Id=T2.randomID
```